# Why it is not possible to use ioremap then remap_pfn_range?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In my driver, I am trying to map an address returned from `ioremap` to a userspace address.

1. What kind of an address is returned from `ioremap`?
2. How is it different from a `kmalloc` address ?
3. How can I map an address returned from `ioremap`?
4. Which address should be inserted to `remap_pfn_range`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need `ioremap()` if you're using `remap_pfn_range()`.  `ioremap()` maps a physical address into a kernel virtual address.  `remap_pfn_range()` maps physical addresses directly to user space.  Just pass your physical address (downshifted by PAGE_SHIFT to produce a pfn) directly to `remap_pfn_range()`.  Your questions in order:

1. kernel virtual address
2. kmalloc returns kernel virtual, but guarantees contiguous memory [See question 116343](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116343/what-is-the-difference-between-vmalloc-and-kmalloc)
3. you could do this if you call `virt_to_phys()` first, to convert kernel virtual address to physical.  But skip a step if you don't actually need kernel access to this memory range
4. physical address, downshifted by PAGE_SHIFT to produce a pfn

Answer (score 0):

`ioremap()` returns the kernel space virtual address. This can't be accessed directly from user space. There is mechanism called mmap(), refer [here](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/multi/kernel_user_space_howto-8.html) and [Mapping physical addresses to virtual address linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621911/mapping-physical-addresses-to-virtual-address-linux/11624608#11624608) for working sample.

Comment: look at #4 at the original post